# ¿Como ocultar un elemento al hacer click fuera de el?

Tags: javascript

Quiero hacer algo asi:

Supongase que hago click en un boton para mostrar un menu, y yo quiero darle click a los elementos que estan dentro de dicho menu, pero al dar click sobre un elemento diferente de ese menu (o los elementos que traiga dentro) este desaparezca.

Comment: En javaScript? no seria mejor con Jquery pero si tu quierres en JavaScript, puedes poner el codigo que llevas hecho.

Answer (score 2):

Esto te servirá (**concepto**):

```
 $(document).on("click",function(e) {

        var container = $("#tu_elemento");

            if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) { 
            //Se ha pulsado en cualquier lado fuera de los elementos contenidos en la variable container

            }
   });
```

Aquí va un **ejemplo funciona**l:

```js
    $(document).on("click",function(e) {
                    
         var container = $("#container");
                            
            if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) { 
               alert("¡Pulsaste fuera!");               
            }
     });
```

```css
    #container {
        background: #fff;
        padding: 20px;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
        color: #555;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



    <div id="container">Pulsa en cualquier lado fuera de este elemento</div>
```

Comment: puedes usar los snippets incluidos en el editor para hacer un ejemplo funcional de verdad xD

Comment: @lois6b por supuesto, es que respondí la pregunta desde el teléfono y no lo puede añadir, cuando llegue a casa lo actualizo. Gracias.

Comment: @lois6b a ejemplo funcional me refería a que funciona xD

Comment: hahah no problem. te lo edité yo, espero que no te moleste. Un saludo

Comment: @lois6b que va jajajaja, gracias